# Registering output to complex variable and placing conditionals on sub-components

Tags: loops, variables, ansible, nested, conditional-statements

I'm getting a bit lost with next variable types and am hoping for some direction in a specific task please:

The Goal:
Based on a list of username:publickey values. I'd like to:

- ensure the user exists on the target system
- if the user does exist then:
  - ensure the "/home/$user/.ssh/authorized_keys" file exists with the correct permissions through the path.

The Scene:

I have a variable:

```yaml
ssh_vars:
  auth_keys:
    bob: "bobs_public_key_string"
    anne: "annes_public_key_string"
    anon: "anons_public_key_string
```

I need to iterate over this variable and for each auth_keys item call a tasklist:

```yaml
- name: loop through the auth_keys and call ssh_dirs.yml for each
  ansible.builtin.include_tasks: "ssh_dirs.yaml"
  loop: "{{ ssh_vars.auth_keys }}"
```

However, I only really want to do this when the auth_key(key) is a user which already exists on the host.

I have been playing with getent, within  "ssh_dirs.yaml":

```yaml
- name: "Ensure the user exists on the target system"
  ansible.builtin.getent:
    database: passwd
    key: "{{ item.name }}"
    fail_key: false
  register: userlookup
```

which creates what i think is a list of dictionaries:

```
ok: [ans-client.local] => {
    "userlookup": {
        "changed": false,
        "msg": "All items completed",
        "results": [
            {
                "ansible_facts": {
                    "getent_passwd": {
                        "bob": [
                            "x",
                            "1003",
                            "1003",
                            "",
                            "/home/bob",
                            "/usr/bin/bash"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "ansible_loop_var": "item",
                "changed": false,
                "failed": false,
                "invocation": {
                    "module_args": {
                        "database": "passwd",
                        "fail_key": false,
                        "key": "bob",
                        "service": null,
                        "split": null
                    }
                },
                "item": {
                    "key": "ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE5AAAAIDvIZuaBhAIGShw21rkvgqyvNePunbVs6OtOBhYJOY2P anne@ans-server",
                    "name": "bob"
                }
            },
            {
                "ansible_facts": {
                    "getent_passwd": {
                        "anne": [
                            "x",
                            "1000",
                            "1000",
                            "anne",
                            "/home/anne",
                            "/bin/bash"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "ansible_loop_var": "item",
                "changed": false,
                "failed": false,
                "invocation": {
                    "module_args": {
                        "database": "passwd",
                        "fail_key": false,
                        "key": "anne",
                        "service": null,
                        "split": null
                    }
                },
                "item": {
                    "key": "ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE5AAAAIKr/76O3hLJlcyZuy7EJxf7sC1z9BSHMuxGsFGBibJY3 anne@ans-server",
                    "name": "anne"
                }
            },
            {
                "ansible_facts": {
                    "getent_passwd": {
                        "anon": null
                    }
                },
                "ansible_loop_var": "item",
                "changed": false,
                "failed": false,
                "invocation": {
                    "module_args": {
                        "database": "passwd",
                        "fail_key": false,
                        "key": "anon",
                        "service": null,
                        "split": null
                    }
                },
                "item": {
                    "key": "SOMEKEY",
                    "name": "anon"
                },
                "msg": "One or more supplied key could not be found in the database."
            }
        ],
        "skipped": false
    }
}
```

But I can't figure out how to isolate this list to ensure the include_tasks: is not called if the user doesn't exist.

```yaml
- name: loop through the auth_keys and call ssh_dirs.yml for each
  ansible.builtin.include_tasks: "ssh_dirs.yaml"
  loop: "{{ ssh_vars.auth_keys }}"
  when: userlookup.results.???????
```

How can I figure out how to reference this nested variable, and how best to isolate a non-missing user?

Something like `userlookup.results.msg is not defined` might work but it's very loose - is there something better I'm missing?

Comment: Please do not add solutions in question. You are welcome to self answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [registering variables with loop](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_loops.html#registering-variables-with-a-loop)

The global idea is

- loop over you var to get the existing/unavailable users
- loop over the results of that previous task for you next one. The original loop variable is available in the `item` key of each result and you can filter as you like.

For your particular case, in a nutshell (untested):

```yaml
- name: Ensure the user exists on the target system
  ansible.builtin.getent:
    database: passwd
    key: "{{ item.name }}"
  register: userlookup
  ignore_errors: true
  loop: "{{ ssh_vars.auth_keys }}"

- name: Call ssh_dirs.yml for each existing users
  ansible.builtin.include_tasks: ssh_dirs.yaml
  loop: "{{ userlookup.results | select('success') }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: user_checked
  vars:
    userloop: "{{ user_checked.item }}"
```

Comment: Thanks for your guidance here.

It's close to solving the problem, however as the registered output from "getent" always populates ansible_facts.getent_passwd, it's always defined even when a user doesn't exist.

As the entry within is "user:[...]"  or "user: null", so it doesn't quite filter as intended.

I did have a play with the getent task, switching on "fail_key: True" and using a dummy "failed_when" statement to prevent failure (poorly) does solve it with this suggested task.

Also I'm not sure what the :
 vars:
    userloop: "{{ user_checked.item }}"

does?

Comment: @another_d Oups my bad! Read you output too fast. Fixed. Please edit your question to remove your solution and provide it as a self answer as already mentioned earlier.

Comment: Thanks for your follow up - your solution works nicely and has opened my (dull) mind to a new method of looping over variables more dynamically - very much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think I've solved it, although maybe there's a better thing to look for in the getent response than just the msg?

The logic and variable reference which works:

```yaml
- name: "Ensure the user exists on the target system"
  ansible.builtin.getent:
    database: passwd
    key: "{{ item.name }}"
    fail_key: false
  register: userlookup
  loop: "{{ ssh_vars.auth_keys }}"

- name: Build a list of usernames which don't exist on the remote host (missing_users)
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    missing_users: "{{ missing_users | default([]) + [usercheck.item.name | string] }}"
  loop: "{{ userlookup.results }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: usercheck
  when: usercheck.msg is defined

- name: loop through the users and ensure the necessary user folders and files are there
  ansible.builtin.include_tasks: "ssh_dirs.yaml"
  loop: "{{ ssh_vars.auth_keys }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: userloop
  when: userloop.name not in missing_users
```

Although this is still checking the `msg:` output mindlessly so only a partial solution